# Android GridView with Separator

Tags: android, gridview

is possible to have a separator between elements of a GridView?

Thanks

Comment: and the question is... how can i display something similar to a table with borders? 
Table View doesn't shows borders neither...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll probably have to play with padding and background colors. Set the background for the table to one color, and the background to each View in the table to another color. Set a 1 or 2 pixel padding around each View in the table, and you should have a border between.

Comment: In your xml for your GridView, use android:horizontalSpacing="1dp" and android:verticalSpacing="1dp" to set a 1 (density independent) pixel padding around each cell for example.

Answer (score 1):

from @FreewheelNat's comment, "In your xml for your GridView, use android:horizontalSpacing="1dp" and android:verticalSpacing="1dp" to set a 1 (density independent) pixel padding around each cell for example. "

this is a much better solution than @Jeff Barger's