# how to create layout for dayview, weekview calendar?

Tags: android, calendar

I want to create layout like this: [dayview](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui)

dose anyone can tell me which layout should i used to make day view calendar like that. I'm going to using absolute layout to process with overlap widget but it's not recommended.

Comment: Hi, did you find how to make a dayview? i'm trying to do it too, but no idea :S:S 

thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a GridView, or maybe a TableLayout.

To get the borders try this trick:
[Android GridView with Separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382736/android-gridview-with-separator)

It's not completely clear which part of the screen you have problems recreating, but I figured it was only the part in the middle with the grid.

BR,
Vanja

Comment: thank you, your trick can resolve well with static cell (display in multicell) , but in dayview mode, user can drag or resize event to other location to change time, so it's not applicable.