# dynamic gridview separator in android

Tags: android, gridview, separator

In my application I have to change the gridview separators dynamically, on user interaction (e.g. horizontal separator with red color, and 1px with; vertical separator with blue color and 2px with...) How can I do this?

I tried this approach [Android GridView with Separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382736/android-gridview-with-separator), but this is not good for me, because I need different colors for the linear and the vertical separators.

I saw this example, too [Android GridView draw dividers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132030/android-gridview-draw-dividers), but I don't know how could I do programmatically(without the xml files).

Any help?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? any picture?

Comment: a table with horizontal and vertical row separators

Comment: row separator by default is vertical, what is horizontal row separator? any picture?

Comment: something like this:[link](http://www.idevice.ro/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/compare.png)

Comment: i don't understand this: """because I need different colors for the linear and the vertical separators""", you need several different colors for one gridview or each gridview should have its own color?

Comment: I need different color only for the horizontal and vertical lines. So what I want to do is to draw the horizontal and vertical lines from code (horizontal line with red color, vertical line with blue color)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item);
a.add("0"); a.add("1"); a.add("2");
a.add("3"); a.add("4"); a.add("5");
a.add("6"); a.add("7"); a.add("8");
a.add("9");
grid.setAdapter(a);
```

where item.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/iten"
    android:textSize="30dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
/>
```

and GridView is defined as:

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:background="@drawable/grid"
    android:listSelector="@null"
/>
```

the most important are two drawables: item.9.png and grid.9.png

item.9.png is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwoah.png)

grid.9.png is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwlVA.png)

the result grid view looks like this

[image]